# How to count word frequencies within a file in python

Tags: python

I have a .txt file with the following format,

```
C
V
EH
A
IRQ
C
C
H
IRG
V
```

Although obviously it's a lot bigger then that, this is essentially it.Basically I'm trying to sum how many times each individual string is in the file (each letter/string is on a separate line, so technically the file is C\nV\nEH\n etc. However when I try to convert these files into a list, and then use the count function on, it separates out letters so that strings such as 'IRQ' are ['\n'I','R','Q','\n'] so then when I count it I get the frequencies of each individual letter and not of the strings.

Here is the code that I have written so far,

```
def countf():
    fh = open("C:/x.txt","r")
    fh2 = open("C:/y.txt","w")
    s = []
    for line in fh:
        s += line
    for x in s:
        fh2.write("{:<s} - {:<d}".format(x,s.count(x))
```

What I want to end up with is an output file that looks something like this

```
C  10
V  32
EH 7
A  1
IRQ  9
H 8
```

Comment: Does it have to be done in python?  `sort yourfile.txt | uniq -c` will give you word counts (you mention C:\ so you seem to be on windows, `sort` and `uniq` are standard unix commands that you can get if you install cygwin or http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @therefromhere - I think the OP wants word counts.  The python code is generating letter counts the way that it is written.  `sort` and `uniq` will technically generate line counts.  Not sure if this is correct or not.

Comment: Word counts, just some of those words happen to be composed of a single letter, it's for biological research. As for doing it in python, that and R are the only languages I'm familiar with and tbh I'd like to figure this out within python

Comment: @D.Shawley yeah sorry I misread - only had one coffee ><  deleted my comment.

Comment: @therefromhere - 'word' needn't be 'english language word'. String would have been better for the OP to use, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [`Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections#collections.Counter), and use `strip()` to remove the `\n`:

```
from collections import Counter
with open('x.txt') as f1,open('y.txt','w') as f2:
    c=Counter(x.strip() for x in f1)
    for x in c:
        print x,c[x]   #do f2.write() here if you want to write them to f2
```

**output:**

```
A 1
C 3
EH 1
IRQ 1
V 2
H 1
IRG 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `s += line` to `s.extend(line.split())`.  The `+=` operator is for adding two sequences together and the string is treated as a sequence of characters.  You can either use `list.append` (e.g., `s.append(line)`) to add the entire line as a single entry in the list or use `list.extend` to add a list of strings.

In this case, I used `line.split()` to split the line into individual words and then added the list of words to the current list.  If each line only contains a single word, then you can use `s.append(line)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ashwini's answer is good if you have Python `2.7` or `3.1`, but `2.6` and `3.0` don't have `collections.Counter`.

For portability to these older versions, you may be better off using [`collections.defaultdict(int)`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects).

Comment: There is [a backport](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/) of `collections.Counter` that is supposed to work with 2.5 and 2.6. Also, this answer should probably be a comment.