# Getting the most frequent word from elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working with the following list:

`["hello, how are you", "hello", "how are you doing","are you ok"]`

*how could I get the frequencies of every word inside of every element?*

All in all the output of the list should look like this:

```
you: 3
are: 3
hello: 2
how: 2
doing: 1
ok: 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count word frequencies within a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117576/how-to-count-word-frequencies-within-a-file-in-python)

Comment: @bobrobbob the question are completely different, I'm dealing with a list and the question that you've flagged me with concerns text files.

Comment: that's not a difference. the logic behind is exactly the same. there are lots of questions in SO regarding the count word problem, it looks very weird to me that not one of them could help you one way or another

Comment: @bobrobbob yeah for sure, some of them have helped me, but they all involved converting my list into a string then counting all the words, which in my opinion isn't the most optimum way. Therefore I wanted to see if there is a specific library or way to do it.

Comment: I would also advise you to take a look at the StackOverflow [help about duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). Which specifically states that "There are many ways to ask the same question, and a user might not be able to find the answer if they're asking it a different way".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from intertools import Counter
import string

l=["hello, how are you", "hello", "how are you doing","are you ok"]

Counter([w.strip(string.punctuation) for s in l for w in s.split() ])
# Counter({'are': 3, 'you': 3, 'hello': 2, 'how': 2, 'doing': 1, 'ok': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `collections.Counter`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import Counter
import string

data = ["hello, how are you", "hello", "how are you doing","are you ok"]
translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)

d = Counter(" ".join(data).translate(translator).split())
#If python2
#d = Counter(" ".join(data).translate(None, string.punctuation).split())

print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
Counter({'are': 3, 'you': 3, 'how': 2, 'hello': 2, 'doing': 1, 'ok': 1})
```

Comment: Output contains `'hello,': 1`

Comment: Yep. just noticed that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def wordListToFreqDict(wordlist):
    wordfreq = [wordlist.count(p) for p in wordlist]
    return dict(zip(wordlist,wordfreq))

def sortFreqDict(freqdict):
    aux = [(freqdict[key], key) for key in freqdict]
    aux.sort()
    aux.reverse()
    return aux

a = ["hello, how are you", "hello", "how are you doing","are you ok"]
wordstring = ' '.join(a)
wordlist = wordstring.split()

wordfreq = [wordlist.count(w) for w in wordlist] # a list comprehension

dictionary = wordListToFreqDict(wordlist)
sorteddict = sortFreqDict(dictionary)

for s in sorteddict: print(str(s))
```

Result:
(3, 'you')
(3, 'are')
(2, 'how')
(1, 'ok')
(1, 'hello,')
(1, 'hello')
(1, 'doing')